Wire Duct fan to ONLY come on when calling for heat or cooling?
First time posting!
So I've had a duct fan booster going to our master bedroom for years and it's worked pretty good. It always came on with the fan. Just the other day we had a new furnace installed and they installed the duct fan wiring with transformer to work just the same. The HVAC installers hooked the duct fan 24V transformer to the EAC filter terminals. With our new furnace we like to leave the fan on continuously just like we did with our last furnace, but I am wondering if there is a way to hook up the booster fan so it only runs when it's calling for heat or air conditioning but not run when the fan is running at low speed continuously? Is this possible at all? I thought about a pressure switch, but since the fan is running continuously I don't know if it would be constantly switched on. Is there any of the 24 V terminals from the thermostat on the HVAC board that could activate my 24V/110v relay only when calling for heat or A/C? Thanks so much in advance!

If I understand your notation correctly you already have a relay with 24 volt coil rated to switch the 120 volt AC mains power drawn by the booster fan. Is that right? If so, simply get another of those relays.
Wire one relay so that its coil connects to W and C (white and common) terminals on the furnace control. Wire the other with its coil connecting to Y and C. In this way the first relay will close during a call for heat and the second will close during a call for cooling.
Connect the switch terminals of the new relay in parallel with the same terminals of the existing relay: common to common, NO (normally open) to NO. When either relay is activated the booster fan will turn on.

Wow! That’s fantastic! Just to double check, W & Y will stay on the entire call for heat or A/C cycle? is there a chance of overloading the HVAC's circuit board 24vac transformer? Thanks so much!
If I could ask one related question, can you recommend a quality 24v coil / 120v AC relay? I’ve had to replace it a couple times they see the last about nine months and then start humming.
Thanks again!!!!
